# App does not start on Android and force close

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-virtual-device

I have created a test scene in Unity which has only one cube and a directional lightening. When installed in AVD just the name of app is display and shows up nothing...

I could not figure out what is the error.. or what is making my application to stop running

AVD setting that is used are
Target: 4.0.3 API Level 15
Skin: HVGA
RAM: 512 VM: 32
Internal Storage: 200MB
SDCARD:2GB

[image: AVD Screenshort]

```
I/AndroidRuntime(  474): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed    
 D/AndroidRuntime(  549):     
 D/AndroidRuntime(  549): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<    
 D/AndroidRuntime(  549): CheckJNI is ON    
 D/AndroidRuntime(  549): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am    
 I/ActivityManager(   77): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.asdasd.cd/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity} from pid 549    
 D/PermissionCache(   36): checking android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER for uid=1000 => granted (22624 us)    
 W/WindowManager(   77): Failure taking screenshot for (130x195) to layer 21005    
 D/AndroidRuntime(  549): Shutting down VM    
 D/dalvikvm(  549): GC_CONCURRENT freed 99K, 77% free 480K/2048K, paused 0ms+1ms    
 I/AndroidRuntime(  549): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed    
 I/ActivityManager(   77): Start proc com.asdasd.cd for activity com.asdasd.cd/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity: pid=559 uid=10041 gids={}    
 W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(   77): setKernelCountSet(10041, 1) failed with errno -2
 I/dalvikvm(   77): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192    
 I/ARMAssembler(   36): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00009002_00000000 [127 ipp] (149 ins) at [0x413fba80:0x413fbcd4] in 869530 ns    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 D/dalvikvm(  559): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.asdasd.cd-2/lib/libmain.so 0x41023f78    
 D/dalvikvm(  559): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/com.asdasd.cd-2/lib/libmain.so 0x41023f78    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3   
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 I/Process (   77): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3    
 I/dalvikvm(  559): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'    
 W/ActivityManager(   77): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!    
 W/ActivityManager(   77): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{411e1ab0 com.asdasd.cd/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity}    
 D/dalvikvm(   77): GC_CONCURRENT freed 294K, 11% free 8687K/9671K, paused 5ms+7ms    
 D/dalvikvm(  160): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 8% free 6992K/7559K, paused 4ms+4ms
```

On Installing on Android the app so similar behavior and generates same similar log

```
I/ActivityManager(  289): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.asdasd.cd/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity bnds=[12,433][125,592]} from pid 546
 I/ActivityManager(  289): Start proc com.asdasd.cd for activity com.asdasd.cd/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity: pid=4268 uid=10130 gids={}
 W/ResourceType(  289): Skipping entry 0x7f040010 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
 W/ResourceType(  289): Skipping entry 0x7f04003d in package table 0 because it is not complex!
 D/dalvikvm( 4268): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.asdasd.cd-1/lib/libmain.so 0x2bde3080
 D/dalvikvm( 4268): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/com.asdasd.cd-1/lib/libmain.so 0x2bde3080
 D/SurfaceFlinger(  136): Release buffer at 0xcddd0
 W/ActivityManager(  289): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
 W/ActivityManager(  289): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{2c57c1e8 com.asdasd.cd/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity}
```

Comment: Looks like a ANR in your application. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

For gaming better to use genymotion dont use AVD that doesn't support EGL rendering and in android 4.4 use dalvik instead of ART ...
Hope you get my point.

Comment: When installing on phone app shows similar behaviour I.e it stops at the first screen having title of the app... my phone is running android 4. 0.4 and unity setting are set to minimum api level 15 ( android 4.0.3)

Comment: I have edited the post and added the log from my device

Comment: There is no error in your code ...
make sure you are using the correct lib and try to run in different device .

Answer (score 0):

Finally my app is working..!:D Problem is solved by updating and applying latest patch unity 4.6.6p1.. which removes the bug from older version .Hope this will help someone having a similar problem